# Ignore an exception in an async method

Tags: c#, .net, async-await, .net-5

I am coding an app (.Net 5) that needs to execute a few async methods. First it creates a Job, then it creates a Task within the job, then waits for the Task to complete, and finally deletes the Job. For context, these are Azure Batch Jobs and Tasks, but I only mention it to indicate that what I call a Task is not the .Net framework Task, but a plain class that just happens to be named that. Other than that, the fact that this is Azure Batch related makes no difference.

I have coded this method to do those steps:

```
    private async Task ExecuteTask(string jobName, string taskName, CloudTask task)
    {
      string poolName = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["PoolName"];
      await taskScheduler.QueueBatchJob(poolName, jobName);
      await taskScheduler.QueueBatchTask(jobName, task);
      taskScheduler.WaitForTaskToComplete(jobName, taskName);
      _ = this.taskScheduler.DeleteJob(jobName); // I am intentionally not awaiting here
    }
```

The calling method has a try / catch, with extra code that may take a while to execute.
I am intentionally not awaiting the DeleteJob method as I don't need for that to be done in order to continue, and I also don't care if it fails. It's there for cleanup but there may later be another process to do proper cleanup.

Now, my question is, what happens if there actually is an error on that method? will it get catch by the parent try/catch if the parent method did not complete? I definitely do not want that so if that is the case, how can I ignore it?

Comment: If you want to know what happens when that code runs then *run it and see what happens* rather than asking strangers on the internet and hoping they're correct.  Once you know what will happen, if you need it to behave differently, and you can't figure out how to accomplish that, *then* you may have a good question on your hands.

Comment: The short answer is it depends. If the `DeleteJob` fails synchronously, then the try/catch in the calling method will catch the exception if the calling method awaits on the return task. If the `DeleteJob` itself is an async state machine, then there wouldn't be exception thrown, but the unobserved exception (if any) will trigger [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.taskscheduler.unobservedtaskexception?view=net-5.0) event.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'll simply answer this question with some quotes from [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2013/march/async-await-best-practices-in-asynchronous-programming):

> Async void methods have different error-handling semantics. When an
> exception is thrown out of an async Task or async Task method, that
> exception is captured and placed on the Task object. With async void
> methods, there is no Task object, so any exceptions thrown out of an
> async void method will be raised directly on the
> SynchronizationContext that was active when the async void method
> started.

later in the same article

> When you await a Task, the first exception is re-thrown, so you can catch the specific exception type (such as InvalidOperationException).

That basically means:
The `Task` returned by the method will contain the `Exception` but it will only be raised if you `await` it. Therefore not awaiting a `Task` results in all Exceptions being swallowed by the `Task` object.

Comment: Thanks. I had red this article but English is my second language and it was too technical to grasp fully. I understood the void part but the not awaiting a task swallowing the exceptions escaped me... and it still does, I read the quotes and I still don't get it. [...] after 5 re-reads I think I may understand the implications now.

Comment: Summary: You dont `await` the `Task` = no `Exception` thrown out of the async method